# Having only one key of many possible keys in Record in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

How can I get autocompletion on the object keys if the keys should be one of the possible strings only?

In the following code, I am getting the required property error. `"must" is missing in type '{ must_not: any; }' but required in type 'Operator'.(2741)`

```
type Operator = Record<"must" | "must_not", any>

const x : Operator = {
  must: ...
}

const y : Operator = {
  must_not: ...
}
```

Where I can have only **one** of the key names at once either "must" or "must_not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a distributive conditional type ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types)) to create a union of singleton objects, one for each key:

```
type SingletonUnion<K extends PropertyKey, T> = K extends any ? {[Key in K]: T} : never
```

(The `K extends PropertyKey` constraint is to prevent incorrect usage, and the `K extends any` constraint is to force distribution.)

```
type Operator = SingletonUnion<"must" | "must_not", any>
// type Operator = { must: any} | {must_not: any}

const x : Operator = {
  must: 'any'
}

const y : Operator = {
  must_not: 'any'
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgOwOYBsLAPYIKoLlgHgGkoIAPYCBAEwGcoAFAJw0idCIhABooAVAHxQAvFBLlKNegEMEIKAH4oAbwDaneYjEBdAFz8AvlH0IIANwhMAUFdCQoAeTbTMTEbESp0WXPgQEAIgBbAFdaYACoAB8oYLDgAH0EDAjeWRABKwB6LKg8gD0FGwBjLHCoMmNHZ1d3ZSs80PD9AHJ0lqsDErLgKHl9J0sXDDdResb4pJTW9s6gA)